# Python: Print all names that start and end with the same letter

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I have a python array of employee names as follows:

```
employees=["Greg McGuiness", "Lola White", "Richard Bright", "Chloe Nelson", "Bradley Long", "Chiara Samos"]
```

I need to print out all names in which first name or last name begin and end with the same letter, in my example it should print these names:

```
Greg McGuiness
Chloe Nelson
Chiara Samos
```

I have been playing around with the regex expressions but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Why "Richard Bright"?

Comment: How does `Richard Bright` fit that criterion? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @TheRootCause Are there no satisfactory answers amongst the 5 provided?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that without regex:

```
for i in employees:
    for name in i.split(' '):
        if name.lower().endswith(name[0].lower()):
            print i
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

Why regex? Here's a terrifying "one liner".

```
from itertools import izip

employees=["Greg McGuiness", "Lola White", "Richard Bright", "Chloe Nelson", "Bradley Long", "Chiara Samos"]

print([
    n for n, (f, l) in izip(employees, (e.split(' ') for e in employees))
    if f[0].lower() == f[-1].lower()
    or l[0].lower() == l[-1].lower()
])
['Greg McGuiness', 'Chloe Nelson', 'Chiara Samos']
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this

```
for employee in employees:
    for name in employee.split(" "):
        if name[0].lower() == name[len(name)-1].lower():
            print(employee)
```

Comment: `name[len(name)-1]` should be written `name[-1]` in idiomatic Python.

Answer (score 2):

I will give a solution with regex.

```
import re
employees=["Greg McGuiness", "Lola White", "Richard Bright", "Chloe Nelson", "Bradley Long", "Chiara Samos"]
print [i for i in employees if re.findall(r"\b(\w)\w*\1\b",i,re.I)]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of true functional one liner :)

```
In [5]:
filter(lambda e: any(x[0].lower() == x[-1].lower() for x in e.split()), employees)
​
Out[5]:
['Greg McGuiness', 'Chloe Nelson', 'Chiara Samos']
```

Or more readable:

```
filter(
  lambda e: any(x[0].lower() == x[-1].lower() 
                for x in e.split()), 
  employees)
```

**Not RE though...**